# Close HDF File After to_hdf() using mode='a'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to save a series of DataFrame using pandas into hdf file. So I use to_hdf()

```
    x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 10), index=pd.date_range(end='1/1/2018', periods=10), columns=list('abcdefghij'))
    x.iloc[:5, :].to_hdf('append.h5', format='table', key='part1', mode='a')
```

After this, I want to check the situation of this hdf file. So I use read_hdf()

```
   y = pd.read_hdf('append.h5', key='part1', mode='r')
```

Obviously, it will shows error：

```
   The file 'append.h5' is already opened, but not in read-only mode (as requested).
```

So I'm just wondering how to close this hdf after to_hdf()?  * I need to set the mode='a' so as to append several tables into this hdf file

Python version 3.6.5

Comment: Hi, which version of Pandas are you using, your code works fine with me. `y = pd.read_hdf('append.h5', key='part1', mode='r')` produces the desired result. 
`               a         b         c         d         e         f  \
2017-12-23  0.043948  0.260736  0.194791  0.775708  0.013273  0.137011   
2017-12-24  0.133136  0.052005  0.105792  0.218531  0.489121  0.688763   
2017-12-25  0.422981  0.217906  0.834061  0.422932  0.636758  0.888885   
....  
  

                   g         h         i         j  
 ...
 `
I'm using pandas 0.22, and it works perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, I tested again and found out that there is no problem now. Maybe I read the file in another script and that leads to this error. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Actually, I sometime observe the same issue when writing something and then quickly reading something afterwards from the same HD5-file. Yet it is hard to reproduce or isolate :(

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 10), index=pd.date_range(end='1/1/2018', periods=10), columns=list('abcdefghij'))
x.iloc[:5, :].to_hdf('append.h5', format='table', key='part1', mode='a')
y = pd.read_hdf('append.h5', key='part1', mode='r')
```

is working (as said in the comments of the question). Would be nice to delete the question or mark it as answered?

Comment: After `df_complete.to_hdf("trial_store.h5", key=key, mode="a", complevel=9, complib="blosc:zstd")` and `df_read = pd.read_hdf("trial_store.h5", key=key, mode="r")`, I get `ValueError: The file 'trial_store.h5' is already opened, but not in read-only mode (as requested).`  Is this a regression? On Fedora Linux with pandas version 1.3.4.  Is there a way to explicitly close the hdf5 file after `.to_hdf`?

Comment: ```import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 10), index=pd.date_range(end='1/1/2018', periods=10), columns=list('abcdefghij'))
x.iloc[:5, :].to_hdf('append.h5', format='table', key='part1', mode='a', complevel=9, complib="blosc:zstd")
y = pd.read_hdf('append.h5', key='part1', mode='r')```

works for me under pandas 1.2.1 . Did you open a separate issue?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Both my and your example works fine now. I can't reproduce the problem ... so I guess everything is OK?